# How to call scalar function in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Can't find it in the Internet.
If someone helps I'll appreciate it greatly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read the [NHibernate documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html), there's a chapter on [querying](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-querying).

Comment: [Link only answers are poor quality answers.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to tell the James from five years ago that.